# How to create an HTML <input> submit button that saves all data to JS variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I know I can create several types of options, questions, checkboxes, and buttons using  in HTML. How can I save the response a user enters and assign it to a variable? Here's the code I'm using right now:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Hotel Name" id="questionOne"><h1 display="block">WHAT IS THE NAME OF THE HOTEL</h1><br>
<input type="button" value="HELLO" onclick="testFunction()">
```

JS:

```
function testFunction() {
    prompt(document.getElementById("questionOne").value;);
}
```

Shouldn't it activate the function when the HELLO button is clicked, and then it identifies the response through the ID "questionOne" and creates a prompt with the variablev value? I don't understand why it's not working.

I'm new to JS and HTML so please don't go crazy if it's a simple answer. Thank you.

Comment: Try this 

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript

Comment: seems like a good use case for forms? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: When select the answer you can store it into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is to do with where things are defined. Rather than using onclick, add an event listener in your js. e.g.

```
document.getElementById ("bar").addEventListener ("click", foo);

function foo() {
    prompt(document.getElementById("questionOne").value);
}
```

and just change the button to have an id and get rid of the onclick:

```
<input type="button" id="bar" value="HELLO">
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! But does that mean the value of the variable questionOne is now whatever I answered the question with? If my answer to the question was "hello" then does variable questionOne == "hello"?

Comment: You mean you want to set the input questionOne value to whatever they put in the prompt? then do something like:
    var hotel = prompt(document.getElementById("questionOne").value);document.getElementById("questionOne").value = hotel;

Comment: if you are actually trying to get them to enter the hotel name in the text box, and save that value, then in your function you can just have var hotel = documen‌​t.getElementById("qu‌​estionOne").value
Just seeing what you commented in the below answer, use alert rather than prompt if you just want to see it so you don't confuse us! Or just console.log()

Comment: I figured it out, thank you! And I changed all my prompts to alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just add event Listener to your input.
Like

```
document.getElementById('questionOne').addEventListener('input',function(){
    var somevariable = prompt(this.value,'');
});
```

That will save the answer of prompt to 'somevariable'.

Comment: I don't want the value of the variable to be the response to the prompt. I want it to be the response to the input. The prompt is merely a way to see if the variable's value changed.